# Autosave with RX in C#

Tags: c#, system.reactive, autosave, rx.net

I want to implement an autosave function. I have two Observables:

- `IObservable<Unit> changes`: emits an item every time the user edits a text
- `IObservable<Unit> saves`: emits a save event every time a save button is pressed

Now i want to combine those to into a 3rd stream **writeBack**. This stream has a subscriber, that writes the current text into a database.

> How do i create the writeBack stream, so that it fullfills the following properties?

- a unsaved change gets written back, if there havent occured any changes for 3 seconds (like *throttle*)
- a save event writes back the last unsaved change immediately

I want to make sure to **only** write back unsaved changes. I dont want to save the text if:

- there is a save event, but no changes
- two save events in a row, but no changes in between
- there is a save event between a change and its autosave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. First we identify times we may want to save:

```
var saveTriggers = changes.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
    .Merge(saves);
```

Next we filter those out to make sure they meet your logic: At least one edit between each save, and the save can't come first. The `SkipWhile` is just there to make sure that Saves that precede changes are ignored. The `Scan` counts the number of changes between each save. We only care when that number goes to 0 (indicating a save was triggered). And `DistinctUntilChanged` filters out consecutive saves.

```
var actualSaves = saveTriggers.Select(_ => EventType.SaveTrigger)
    .Merge(changes.Select(_ => EventType.Edit))
    .SkipWhile(et => et == EventType.SaveTrigger)
    .Scan(0, (editCount, eventType) => eventType == EventType.SaveTrigger ? 0 : editCount + 1)
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .Where(count => count == 0)
    .Select(_ => Unit.Default);
```

and using enum class

```
enum EventType
{
    SaveTrigger,
    Edit
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does exactly what it should. I have found my own solution, but it used Windows with delayed streams and was way to complex. This one is much easier. Good idea to use Scan.

Comment: Thanks. Anytime you're looking at a logic in terms of history, `Scan` should be the first thing you look to.